# Rails - Form dropdowns for nested resources. What's the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an edit screen for a model that's nested inside 2 other resources.  To make the example easy to understand, it looks sort of like this:

Make ->  Model -> Car

I have a Car edit screen that lets you edit the few fields that it contains.
*(assume the url is:  /makes/124/models/12512/cars/1125/edit)*

I want to add a cascading pair of dropdowns to allow the user to re-assign a car to a different make/model.  (I'm doing this to clean up some of the bad data that's in the system).

The form looks like this:

```
<% form_for [@car.model.make, @car.model, @car] do |f| %>

    <%= f.error_messages %>

        <!-- this is where I want the cascading dropdowns -->   

    <p> <%= f.label :color %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :color %></p>

    <p> <%= f.label :mileage %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :mileage %></p>

    <p><%= f.submit "Update Car" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I can add @makes to this view from my controller, and I know how to make the select box, but what I don't understand is how I can have the value automatically selected when the form loads.

**What's the correct way to build such a form, with fields for some of the parent resources?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:shallow => true` as described [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) so that your edit URI is `http://host:port/cars/1125/edit`

Comment: Actually I have friendly-looking routes, so the full URL has meaning, though I'd agree with you if I was just using the id for each one.  (Something like /makes/52-honda/12-accord/ .....) -  The other reason is that the URL is "hackable" meaning you can take a segment off and it still works.